# Roughly when were these Pegasus photos taken?

Tags: history, launch-vehicle, first-flight

This [NASA Spaceflight Tweet](https://twitter.com/nasaspaceflight/status/585092870652239872) shows historical photos of (presumably) Antonio Elias wishing Pegasus well.

**Question:** Does anyone know roughly when were these Pegasus photos taken? Could they be circa the first flight in 1990? Before or after?

Clearly it worked in any case. After 25 years and 37/42 successful launches, Pegasus II is coming.

The tweet links to this article: [Pegasus Celebrates a Quarter of a Century Milestone](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2015/04/pegasus-celebrates-quarter-century-milestone/). Some more info and photos from that timeframe can be found in the video below.

> [image]

Some more history from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oY3GclS5VUQ), including Kubrick's *other* propulsion-related film.

Comment: The photo to the right was uploaded to nasaspaceflight.com on `2015-04-06`.

Comment: I looked through the Aviation Week back issue archive for 1990 but didn't find the pictures.  In the pix and then video, you can see how Dr. Elias has aged, though (as we all do).

Comment: @OrganicMarble though not all of us reach the desired level of mental maturity that those around us would prefer (I certainly haven't).

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thank you for the research by the way! Were you checking online archives, or the variety found stacked in the corner of a closet?

Comment: haha, I used to subscribe, but I threw out all but a couple issues.  They have a great online archive of all the issues. You have to register, but I think it's free - although there is a chance I'm still using the login from when I subscribed. http://archive.aviationweek.com/  I remember reading about Pegasus when I subscribed, in those ancient pre Internet days.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be on the internet before 2015. https://www.scoopnest.com/user/NASASpaceflight/585092870652239872-giving-his-baby-a-good-luck-kiss-orbitalatk-pegasus-designer-antonio-elias-photos- might be the first time it showed up.